# Update database with php button in accordion

Tags: php, html, mysql

i have the following code that displays the entries in a db table in separate accordions. Within these accordions i've included buttons meant to alter some row entries but i don't really know how to start it in this case.

Here's the code

```
<?php
                $sql = "SELECT formid, username, formstatus  FROM forms";
                if(!empty($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['form_id'])){
                $action = $_POST['action'];
                $formId = $_POST['form_id'];

                $newStatus = null;

                if($action == 'accept_form'){
                    $newStatus = "Accepted";
                } else if($action = 'deny_form') {
                    $newStatus = "Denied";
                } else {
                    //Action is neither accept_form or deny_form
                }

                if($newStatus !== null){
                $updateFormStatus = $con->prepare('UPDATE `nopforms` SET `nopstatus` = ? WHERE `id` = ?');
                if($updateFormStatus !== false){
                $updateFormStatus->bind_param('si', $newStatus, $formId);  
                    if($updateFormStatus->execute()){
                echo "Success";
            } else {
                //Error has occurred when updating form status.
                echo "Fail";
            }
        } else {
            print_r($con->error_list); //It is just for debug purposes, shouldn't be used in production. It is not a good idea to show raw errors to user.
        }
    }
}
                $result = $con->query($sql);
                $i = 0; 
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $i++;
                $nopid = $row["nopid"];
                $username = $row["username"];
                $nopstatus = $row["nopstatus"];


                echo "<div class='pnel-group' id='accordion".$i."'>
                <div class='panel panel-default'>
                    <div class='panel-heading'>
                        <h4 class='panel-title'>
                            <a data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#accordion".$i."' 
                                    href='#collapse".$i."'>Form ID: ".$formid." | Student Name: ".$studentname."
                            </a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id='collapse".$i."' class='panel-collapse collapse'>
                        <div class='panel-body'>                        
                        <b>Username: </b>".$username."<br>
                        <b>Form status: </b>".$nopstatus."<br>


                        </div>
                        <hr>
                        <div class='panel-footer'>
                         <form method='post'>
                         <input type='hidden' name='nop_id' value='".$nopid."'>
                            <button class='btn btn-success' type='submit' name='action' value='accept_form'>Accept Form</button>
                            <button class='btn btn-danger' type='submit' name='action' value='deny_form'>Deny Form</button>
                        </form>

                    </div>

                </div>
                <hr>
            </div>

                ";
                }
                } else {
                echo "There aren't any NoP's submitted!";
                }


                ?>
```

What i want to achieve is when the user presses the deny or accept button to change the value in the $formstatus row from the specified accordion. 
Thanks for your time

Comment: I guess it's kinda hard to happen? :P

Comment: Does your _forms_ database table has _id_ field? You would probably like to include it somehow to the button action so the script know which row to modify. Do you want to accomplish this by ajax or just sending form and reloading a page? Do you use PDO or MySQLi?

Comment: Yes it does have an id set as PK. I don't wanna mix up things up with ajax just pure php with echo as success messages. Using MySQLi

Comment: What value would "Accept Form" and "Deny Form" buttons set to _formstatus_?

Comment: Accepted or Denied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your buttons to send form with *id* of form you want to modify *fomrstatus* of, and buttons itself can be an action to do, either accept or deny form.

It may look like this (Keep in mind it is a part of php string, and I'm embedding there **$formid** variable):

```
<div class='panel-footer'>
    <form method='post'>
        <input type='hidden' name='form_id' value='".$formid."'>
        <button class='btn btn-success' type='submit' name='action' value='accept_form'>Accept Form</button>
        <button class='btn btn-success' type='submit' name='action' value='deny_form'>Deny Form</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Then before you selecting rows from database, so before `$result = $con->query($sql);` you need to check if there is action to handle:

```
if(!empty($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['form_id'])){
    $action = $_POST['action'];
    $formId = $_POST['form_id'];

    $newStatus = null;

    if($action == 'accept_form'){
        $newStatus = 1;
    } else if($action = 'deny_form') {
        $newStatus = 0;
    } else {
        //Action is neither accept_form or deny_form
    }

    if($newStatus !== null){
        $updateFormStatus = $con->prepare('UPDATE `forms` SET `formstatus` = ? WHERE `id` = ?');
        if($updateFormStatus !== false){
            $updateFormStatus->bind_param('ii', $newStatus, $formId);  
            if($updateFormStatus->execute()){
                //Form status has been updated successfuly.
            } else {
                //Error has occurred when updating form status.
            }
        } else {
            var_dump($con->errno, $con->error); //It is just for debug purposes, shouldn't be used in production. It is not a good idea to show raw errors to user.
        }
    }
}
```

So the idea is to check if both parameters exists, then check if it is accept_form or deny_form and prepare value for formstatus.

I used there integers but you can use string if you really want it, but it will be probably faster to compare column value against integer then string if you ever want to select only accepted/denied forms.

Then I check if new status has been prepared (is strictly not null) (if action is neither accept_form nor deny_form then it won't be prepared and will stay null), and prepare update statement then execute it.

Then you selecting rows from *forms* and build html, at the time it will be updated.

Comment: Hello and sorry for the late answer. I've read your answer and it seems logical indeed. I've tried but when i press any of the 2 buttons i get an error saying: Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\management\pendingnforms.php on line 130.

Comment: You see, when preparation of statement fails, `mysqli::prepare` will return `FALSE`, so there is something wrong with the query I wrote, you can check if `$updateFormStatus` is not false, and if it is not then bind and execute, but if it is, you can access last errors by eg. `print_r($con->error_list)`. I will try to update my post to include error handling for statement preparation.

Comment: If i change $newStatus = "Accepted"; inside if($action == 'accept_form') then i will need to update the bind_param from 'ii' to 'si' right ?. Just checking to see if that error is from my mistakes.

Comment: I've included your code for error handling, but all i get is Array ( )

Comment: That's right, it will be `'si'`, and I have modified my code, it may be that error_list applies only to queries, I don't really know, try with errno and error.

Comment: tried with error and it works, seems i had a wrong id value in query. Thanks a lot !!